# Passing python file reading command through CMD in C#

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

I am facing problem while sending reading python command in CMD through C#. Actually I have to open file in cmd and then pass several commands like reading db and passing other constraints to my python file from GUI which is devloped in C#. Here is my code

I have tried with cmd.exe and also with FULL_PATH_To_PYTHON/Python.exe but I am unable to open file and then send command like reading db.
In cmd i do it by opening file ike `python -i saddle.py` but here this command is not working like I tried `proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("python -i saddle.py");` but system crashes.
I even found IronPython for this solution but don't know that that will solve my problem as I don't know about how to read its output in textbox.

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\..\saddle";
            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = false;
            var proc = Process.Start(psi);

            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("saddle.py");
           // proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("open_db(['db/generic.xml', 'db/generic-server.xml','db/intel-xeon-2600.xml', 'db/intel-xeon-phi.xml','db/memory.xml', 'db/network.xml', 'db/hdd.xml','db/ssd.xml'])");
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Output1.Text = s;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this to run the command on cmd from your C# string

```
string command = "python -i saddle.py";
```

and then

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",command);
```